# Error in FileUtils.copyUrlToFile

Tags: java, eofexception, fileutils, apache-commons-io

I am executing the below code to pull the .gz file from a URL to a local directory.For small files it goes through fine but for large files it downloads only part of it but does not fail. I get to know the error only when I try to UNZIP it. Can someone throw any light on this on what could be the reason.

```
public boolean downloadFilemethod(String filePath, String url, String 
decompressFilePath) { 
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filePath) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(url)) { 
try { 
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), new File(SRC_BASE_DIR + filePath), 
TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS); 
ingestmethod(filePath,decompressFilePath);   
downloadSuccess = true; 
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) 
{ LOG.warn("some message"); } 
catch (IOException e) 
{ LOG.warn("some message); 
} 
}
return downloadSuccess 
}
```

Comment: What library does `FileUtils` belong to?

Comment: There is a tag: `FileUtils` or `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` is File manipulation utility from [Apache Commons] :D Read carefully whole question ;)

Comment: Its from Apache commons : org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Comment: What does the surrounding code look like?

Comment: @matt: Once I download the file into local temp  directory I move it into Hadoop and unzip it.When I try to unzip it I face an error "java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream" which means the input .gz file was not fully downloaded.

Comment: I am more interested in actually seeing the surrounding code to verify that there are no exceptions that are being squashed, etc.

Comment: public boolean downloadFilemethod(String filePath, String url, String decompressFilePath) {
  
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filePath) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(url)) {
   try {
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), new File(SRC_BASE_DIR + filePath), TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS);
    ingestmethod(filePath,decompressFilePath);
    downloadSuccess = true;
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    LOG.warn("some message");
    
   } 
    
    catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.warn("some message);
   }
  }
return downloadSuccess
}

Comment: Pleas edit question and put this code inside question.

Comment: Perhaps `try (InputStream stream = new GZIPInputStream(new URL(url).openStream())) { Files.copy(stream, Paths.get(decompressFilePath)); }` will work better?  (And as a bonus, no third-party libraries required.)